# How to create a library dependent on other libraries (Java, libgdx)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I have been using libGdx for about a year now, and i have created a set of closely related classes that together makes up a practical "module" for use in other libgdx projects.

"module" in a literal sense.

At first i wanted to make just that, modules (using the java module as a literal module). But then i thought, why not just make libraries instead.

The important part for me is re-usability, so firstly:

**1. What's the difference between a module and a library? Would you just make a module and copy-paste it between projects or make a library?**

Probably not how you should use a java module. I'm currently reading more about java modules.

additional context:
The set of classes contains classes that's only used internally and some for use externally as public "would be library" classes. The "module" is somewhat like a program in itself, with input / output classes. And the idea is to build my project on bricks like this. So i'm confused about how to make it modular. I thought making them libraries and import them into future libgdx projects could be the way to go.

Either way, the title question will be raised later at some point anyway.

---

**Some general practical info:** (I include how i would go about making a library, which may or may not be relevant. **Skip this section to get to the question**)

For testing purposes i made a new project and included some libgdx libraries.

(i have them in a "lib" folder within my project or usually in an external folder that every new project use. on IntelliJ i go to file - project structure - libraries. And find the gdx .jar files to include.)

I make an arbritrary class extending a gdx class.

From here i want to make a library. (Or a .jar file of the project)

From my understanding, that's how to go about making a library.

I tried to do that in IntelliJ:

(On Eclipse it looked simpler on a youtube tutorial. Just right-clicking a package and export as .jar)

IntelliJ: File - Project structure - Artifacts - (+) Add Jar -> from modules with dependencies.

I select a module with the project name. (I guess if you had more modules within the project you could select them as well)

Since it's a library i assume you leave the Main class path empty.

I have "extract to the target JAR" selected. and press ok.

This comes up:

[image]

At this point i don't know what i am looking at.

I press apply/ok.

From here i go to Build - Build artifact. Select the .jar file and Build.

So now i have a .jar file that i can import into a new project.

But this .jar file also includes the libgdx libraries it's dependant on.

So i guess you could just merge the gdx libraries with your library / libraries and just include one single .Jar file of all of them?

---

So:

**2. What is the proper way to make / include libraries. And how would you go about making a library that depends on other libraries? I don't really wan't to have the libgdx libraries inside my library. I want to include the libgdx libraries as usual. And then include my library that should be dependent on the libgdx ones in some way, but not have them included inside of them.**

I have heard about Maven and Gradle, but i'm not familiar with them. Is this something i should use for this or can i do without?

Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should start with [*Understanding Java 9 Modules
What they are and how to use them*](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html)

Comment: Yeah. It would be a good idea to know more than the basics and main uses.

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely use a build tool like Maven and Gradle to make a library. You just configure the dependencies you need, and they are not included in your own library.

My recommendation for you is to use Gradle as the build tool, GitHub as the service and Jitpack to publish the library. Now paste these names into your preferred search engine and get going. :-)

Comment: Well, i've seen a lot of people writing highly about gradle and how it makes things more streamlined. So i might just have to find out what the fuss is about :)